# Populating a calendar with information

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following jQuery calendar: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/568/astonishing-iCal-like-calendars-with-jQuery

I'd like to populate it using the following query:

```
public function get_upcoming_events()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM events
            WHERE date >= NOW()
            ORDER BY date ASC";

    return DB::get_results($query);
}
```

I've set out to populate the popup boxes with event information in a similar format to this.

```
    echo '<li><span class="title">'.date('n/j/Y', strtotime($event->date)).' - '.$event->title.'</span>';
    echo '<span class="desc"><a href="'.SITE_URL.'/index.php/events/get_event?id='.$event->id.'">Click here for details and to sign up...</a></span></li>';
```

I have now downloaded an extension for this: https://github.com/MrHus/jquery-monthly-ical/tree/ Following the documentation I've changed this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("#ical").ical({

    eventdates: [{"date": "2009-03-21", "title": "My birthday", "desc": "Its my birthday!"},
                 {"date": "yyyy-01-01", "title": "New Year", "desc": "Its a new year!"},
                 {"date": "2009-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                 {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                 {"date": "2010-09-01", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention."}, 
                 {"date": "2010-09-02", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention day two."}, 
                 {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "Towl", "desc": "Dont forget to bring a towl."}    
                ]                   
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("#ical").ical({

                        <?php
                        foreach($events as $event)
                        {
                        ?>
                        eventdates: [{"date": "<?php date('Y/m/d') ?>", "title": "<?php $event->title ?>", "desc": "Its my birthday!"},
                                     {"date": "yyyy-01-01", "title": "New Year", "desc": "Its a new year!"},
                                    ]
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>                 
});
```

How do I populate the popup boxes calendar with the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `get_upcoming_events` is in working order and you fetch an array of objects, you can use a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop:

```
// $events is the fetched array
foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo '<li><span class="title">'.date('n/j/Y', strtotime($event->date)).' - '.$event->title.'</span>';
    echo '<span class="desc"><a href="'.SITE_URL.'/index.php/events/get_event?id='.$event->id.'">Click here for details and to sign up...</a></span></li>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however to make it fully functional, how do I tell it to display `<td class="today">` on Today's day and `<td class="date_has_event">` on date where there are events present?

Comment: You should use a separate query to select all dates in the current month that have events to include both past and future events (let's call it `$dates_with_events`), and then perhaps use something like `foreach(range(1, date('t') as $date) {if (in_array($date, $dates_with_events)){/* date has event */}}`

Comment: I have used the extension for iCal and I've tried to put a foreach, however it doesn't work. I've edited my original post to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: Try replacing that eventdates array with `echo json_encode($events)`.  Also, in the future, you have to use `echo` in order for the content to be output to the browser.  BTW, this code really should have been included with your question, because it makes our previous answers less applicable to your problem.